# How to install Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

According to the documentation provided by Microsoft's [Write unit tests for C/C++ in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp) Visual Studio includes 4 unit testing framework for C++ by default without any extra installs required. However when I try to add a unit test framework only Google Test is shown. In my second screenshot I show that I have these framework installed. How do I get Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++?

[image]
[image: screenshot of installed testing frameworks]

Comment: Did you ever find out? I'm curious too.